# 1996 Chevy Tahoe Won't Start

Tags: electrical

My Tahoe won't turn over. There are no clicking sounds. Lights will turn on. Nothing happens when I turn the key.

Comment: What have you checked so far?

Comment: do you have a meter or 12v test probe?

Comment: Please don't shout.

Comment: What hillsons is saying is that it's customary to use lowercase letters, while only capitalizing the first word in a sentence. This will help people take your problem more seriously. :) Hope this helps!

Comment: well i am sorry from the high case letters had no idea,i check the battery and the relays,going to put a meter on the starter,for mike yes i do have a meter.Thankyou guys Ray

Answer (score 4):

1.Check for 12 on the battery +post to -post.

2.Check for 12v on the +cable terminals,both ends at the battery and and the solenoid.

3.Check +post to the engine block you should have 12 volts (verifies a ground)

4.While the key is at "start" the small solenoid wires should have 12v

5.If you have 12v at the solenoid and it doesn't click it is bad.
If you don't have 12v at the solenoid with the key at the start position you need a wiring diagram to start probing for where the 12v stops.

Comment: Well thankyou Mike i will get it hell today to see we could locate this promblem.